# Custom button from jquery dialog not calling controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have main view and open a dialog by using the jquery dialog like below.

```
function ShowDialog() {

    dialog = $('#reassign').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 700,
        modal: true,

        open: function () {
            $('#reassign').load('/ItemsList/Reassign');
        }
    });
    dialog.dialog("open");
```

}

The content of the dialog is in a `PartialView`. I have a button on that dialog and I want to call another action to load a list of users. This how I call the action method. But its not getting fired.

```
$('#searchUser').click(function () {
        var search = $('#search').val();
        alert(search);
        $.ajax({
            ur1: '@(Url.Action("Users", "WorkItemsList"))',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is "not getting fired"? Is the click event not fired? Did you use your browser's debugger tools or Fiddler to check whether an ajax request is indeed sent to the server?

Comment: I checked with fiddler. I see a call when in fiddler when I click the button. But its not hitting the break point on my controller. Also the fiddler doesnt show any URL. It just shows /

Comment: When du you execute second js code? are you execute it after load html into dialog? And you have typo `ur1` should be `url`.

Comment: The second js is called after the html is loaded. Just a search textbox for the user to enter some text and do a search to get a result.

Comment: @py3r3str - Thank you. that was the mistake.Now my method is getting fired.